# Chrome extension preserve html data

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension which has a popup.html which holds a large jstree. What I would like to do is this: The first time the user clicks the popup after the browser window opens, the data used to populate the jstree is fetched. Subsequent clicks of the popup will have the generated html preserved so the tree no longer needs to be generated.

In other words, I only want to generate the jstree once and have the popup keep the contents of its html in memory. Is this doable?

Here is the popup.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    function logIt(text) {
        backgroundPage.console.log(text);
    }

    function buildUI(feedData) {
        $('#jstree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'animation': 0
            },

            'json_data': feedData,

            'themes': {
                'theme': 'classic',
                'dots': false,
                'icons': true
            },

            'types': {
                'valid_children': [ 'folder' ],
                'types': {
                    'folder': {
                        'valid_children': [ 'file' ],
                        'max_depth': 1
                    },
                    'file' : {
                        'valid_children': [ 'none' ],
                        'icon': { 'image': 'images/file.png' }
                    }
                }
            },

            'plugins': [
                'json_data',
                'themes',
                'sort',
                'types',
                'search'
            ]
        })
        .on('click', '.jstree-leaf', function() {
            logIt($(this).text());
        });
    }


    chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action': 'fetchFeed'}, function(response) {
        var output = JSON.parse(response);
        buildUI(output.data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it is doable, you can use storage provided by chrome extensions. The related code will go in your listener which is listening to your `sendRequest`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I can store the JS object which is used to build the jsTree object. jsTree builds the HTML from the JS object. This is the part that takes a couple seconds. Every time I click the popup, the object is fetched from the background page and I have to wait 1-2 seconds before I see my jsTree. What I want is to have the generated HTML be preserved in popup.html so it appears immediately. :) If you have an example I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`window.localstrorage` is available inside `popup.html`. So you can store the data in localStorage. But you will have to serialize/deserialize every time there is a save/retrieve operation. That shouldn't be a concern unless your jstree is gigantic (Tip: You can use `eval` for deserializing freely unless you are expecting data from third party sources).

You can use `indexedDB` as well, that will save you from serialize/deserialize overhead.

## Update

I remember there was a storage api for chrome extensions `chrome.storage`. `chrome` object is available both at `background.html` and `popup.html`. Its advantages are

- Simple API.
- It doesn't require you to deserialize the data for storing.
- Its asynchronous. So UI doesn't block while retrieving. But the gain is not relevant in this case since because its inside the context of `popup.html` which will close anyway if you try to navigate away, so its same as blocking the UI.
- You can sync data using google sync so user can access data from multiple instances of chrome/chromium with which user uses your extensions. And this is the big one.

P.S. You will need `storage` permission if you are to use `chrome.storage` api.

## UPDATE

See my pull request [#1](https://github.com/gdanko/delicious-chrome/pull/1). I have implemented the api;

Comment: Do you have an example I could see?

Comment: And what would I actually store? I want to preserve the DOM structure so the next time the popup is opened, jsTree does not have to rebuild the tree. Maybe I can store the jsTree object itself?

Comment: You can choose to store either a JSON object and then build the tree or you can also choose to store the html generated.

Comment: I don't have a working example since I haven't written chrome extensions in a while. If you want me to help you with code, you can set up a minimal chrome extension with essentials of what you want to do on [github](http://github.com), I will fork your project and write the storage code for you.

Comment: tell me how I can contact you and I will email you the link.

Comment: It is the jsTree sort function killing performance. If I disable sorting, the speed is acceptable.

Comment: Sorry didn't get a chance to check SO over the weekend, I will get back to you shortly.

Comment: I've sent you [this pull request](https://github.com/gdanko/delicious-chrome/pull/1). Lets have rest of our communication on github itself through github issues. I am following your repo. Meanwhile if you think its working after my commit, mark this as correct answer.

Comment: You original question was about storing (caching) the data. This answers the original question.